# Conditional jQuery Form Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I am validating a form using jQuery validate, is it possible to only validate the form if certain conditions are met? in my case if a value in a dropdown which is not part of the form has been selected has

Answer (score 0):

dont place problem in words instead use your programming code samples so it will be easy to understand to other.

Comment: dont post comments as answers